# How to solve "unexpected keyword argument" with python-attrs construct, so that mypy is happy?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing, python-attrs

I have a `class A` in a foreign library.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, a: int):
        self.a = a
```

I would like to extend a `class B` with `A` like:

```py
import attr

@attr.s
class B(A):
    b: int = attr.ib()
```

The code seems to work:

```py
import attr

class A:
    def __init__(self, a: int):
        self.a = a

attr.s(these={
    "a": attr.ib(type=str)
}, init=True)(A)

@attr.s(kw_only=True)
class B(A):
    b: int = attr.ib()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = A(1)
    b = B(a=1, b=2)
    print(a)  # output: A(a=1) 
    print(b)  # output: B(a=1, b=2)
```

but mypy/pyright is unhappy.

```sh
> mypy file.py
error: Unexpected keyword argument "a" for "B"
```

Answer (score 1):

I’m reasonably sure that the MyPy attrs plugin doesn’t support `these`.

Since you’re not calling `super`, the idiomatic way would be to just define `a` as an attribute on `B` so that attrs takes care of it.

---

JFTR: if you use `@attr.define` or `@attr.s(auto_attribs=True)`, you can leave out the `attr.ib()` call(s).

Comment: Thanks, @hynek. This was an important hint. Erroneously I thought that `attrs` doing some magic to make a `super()` behind the scenes. In the meantime I changed it to `@attr.define`. Pretty sad that mypy doesn't support it properly.

Comment: `attrs` does _never_ super (each method is optimized for each case). If _you_ need to call super, there’s ways to achieve that: https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/init.html#hooking-yourself-into-initialization